Women doctors vs woman doctors
In English, noun modifiers are not marked for number. One says "cowboy boot" and "cowboy boots", not "cowboys boots".
So I'm often confused when I see people write (for instance) "women doctors" instead of "woman doctors", or "women writers" instead of "woman writers". This practice seems to be standard in many publications, e.g. the New York Times.
Is there a linguistic explanation for this? Thank you!!!

Thank you all. But, my question is about marking for number (singular vs plural), and not about marking for gender.

Okay, so male dancers, female dancers. And female or  male  doctors. However, we'd also write: doctors who are women, so woman doctor, singular,  and women doctors, plural. The same goes for writers: a woman writer and women writers. It depends on the main noun. I can enter this as an answer but it's rathe basic.

I also think that any rule about plural form of compound nouns is language-specific. E.g. French noun loup-garou "werewolf" has plural loups-garous (with -s for each element). It is imaginable that plural form of English noun werewolf could be wereswolves :) .

There's a well-known pattern where nouns that have irregular plurals are more acceptable as modifiers in the plural form than regular nouns. The other day my partner naturally said the phrase geese poop, but I don't think any native English speaker would refer to chickens poop.

@TKR With irregular nouns, it would match the modified noun: goose poop [as poop is uncountable [sigh]); but geese turds, which is countable. Sorry for the scatology.  chicken as attributive is just chicken. However, bear  in mind the Brits do do this: drugs policy.  But that's another story. They use attributives in the plural sometimes.

@Lambie I've never heard of that rule, and I don't think it exists for most speakers. For me "geese poop" and "geese turds" are equally acceptable (though only grammatically).

@TKR Let's trust the med schools, Yale, for example:  https://medicine.yale.edu/news/yale-medicine-magazine/article/women-physicians-over-the-centuries/  or  the AMA: Women Physicians Section https://www.ama-assn.org/member-groups-sections/women-physicians/women-medicine

@Lambie Obviously "women physicians" is normal English. I'm saying that the rule about irregular noun modifiers matching the number of the modifier noun isn't one I've ever heard of. Would you say "one foot warmer" but "two feet warmers"?

@TKR A woman physician is also right, it can be singular or plural depending on the word physician. Because: a woman is a physician but a foot is not a warmer.

There is quite an extensive literature about the pattern mentioned by TKR that irregular plurals are more acceptable as modifiers than regular plurals. This has nothing to do with whether the head noun is plural, as shown by examples in e.g. Haskell et al. (2003, in Cognitive Psychology 47):

rat-eater, *rats-eater
mouse-eater, mice-eater

Haskell et al. mention previous explanations based on rule ordering. On such accounts (they mention e.g. Kiparsky 1982; Pinker 1994, 1999), compounds and regular plurals are generated by rules, but irregular plurals are stored in the lexicon. Under the assumption that the compound formation rule applies before regular plural formation, regular plurals are unavailable in compounds, but irregular plurals are (I follow Pinker here; Kiparsky assumes that irregular plurals are generated by a rule prior to compound formation).
There are problems with these approaches, because of exceptions (awards ceremony; pilots union) as well as other problems that I will not go into here. To account for these exceptions, others have suggested that the rule-based account be extended with semantic and phonological constraints to allow exceptions where needed. What Haskell et al. propose is that these semantic and phonological constraints are powerful enough on their own, and that a rule-based account is no longer necessary:

We developed an alternative account in which the well-formedness of these constructions is a function of a constraint-satisfaction process that weighs multiple types of probabilistic information. [...] We began by identifying two primary constraints, one semantic and one phonological. Roughly speaking, on this account the acceptability of a modiﬁer is a function of how semantically and phonologically similar it is to singular nouns.

Haskell et al. further explain how these constraints can be learned:

The phonological constraint reﬂects the fact that, although their phonological properties are highly varied, modifiers do not tend to have the phonological form of regular plurals [...] How this negative generalization could be learned is illustrated by connectionist models [...] The weights on connections between units are set on the basis of exposure to positive examples. The weights represent a set of simultaneous probabilistic constraints that are evaluated every time an example is processed. The well-formedness of a novel input depends on how well it ﬁts the constraints embodied by the weights.

And:

The semantic constraint arises in a similar manner. The child learns that although the semantics of modifiers are highly varied, they do not tend to include number. Given a choice between a singular and a plural form, the singular form is preferred because it is a closer approximation to a number-neutral form.

The case of woman doctor is a bit different, because woman can be understood both as an attribute and as an object:

Attribute: a doctor who is a woman (cf. woman birdwatcher)
Object: a doctor who treats women (cf. woman hater; mouse-eater)

Mice-eater above corresponds to women doctor, which only has the latter interpretation. However, this objective interpretation licenses women doctors ('doctors who treat women'). Though I have not found literature on it just now, one might hypothesize that the pattern then spread from objective to attributive interpretations, so that women doctors can now mean 'female doctors' as well. This is a hypothesis that would have to be checked, and I'm open to alternatives.

Not sure I quite buy the last paragraph here. Google and Ngrams inform me that there are in fact some people who use women(-)hater, but it’s much, much rarer than woman(-)hater, which is also the only form I’ve ever heard. But more importantly, has woma/en doctor ever been used to mean ‘doctors who treat women’? I have personally only ever heard the attributive meaning, so I find it less likely that this should have spread from an objective meaning. There is also the fact that the plural of the head noun does make a difference: going by Ngrams, woman doctor greatly outnumbers →

→ women doctor, while women doctors greatly outnumber woman doctors; similarly, woman hater greatly outnumbers women hater while in the plural, women haters outnumbered woman haters until about ten years or so ago, after which woman haters has seemingly increased drastically.

@JanusBahsJacquet Thanks for looking that up, I agree it doesn’t look good for that hypothesis then.

woman + doctor is not like mouse + eater. a woman is a doctor. can give us a woman doctor (two meanings, depending on context) whereas a mouse who is an eater is not a mouse eater.

@Lambie I address this at the end of my answer, and see also the discussion with JanusBahsJacquet.

I  think they are fundamentally different. And I don't even understand that first sentence in that pararaph. Also, I don't understnd your hypens, as in mice-eater. Would you say: meat-eaters? Anyway, I think that woman doctor is only secondarily a doctor who treats women and in informal spoken contexts.

@Lambie the hyphen is taken from the original paper.
